# Can I render at 50fps instead of 60fps, what are the drawbacks?

Tags: frame-rate

When reading on frame rate, I usually encounter the following suggestions:

- render as fast as possible
- render to 60 fps

I want to make a 2d game that runs in slow computers, and i've been surprised by how Cave Story smooth is and that it runs at 50 fps. Maybe. there is not much difference between 50 and 60, but if i dont have a reason to use 60, i'd rather set my frame rate to 50.

I'd like to know the drawbacks of this approach, specially applied to my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Specifically for display refresh rate*, it's not really much of a choice, it's more of a mandate, and there's no reason not to go for this. The reason is that
a lot of underlying technologies / rendering engines opt for syncing with the hardware (vsync) which typically updates at about 60Hz (this figure primarily for historical reasons - it was closely associated with the frequency of AC current in the days of analog television - see PAL / NTSC).

Understand the reason behind vsync: Without it, you may get partway through painting a frame before a hardware update triggers, leading to *tearing* that you may have seen in windowed games. At best, you'll get frames that don't tear, but also don't sync nicely to your monitor's rate, resulting in a less-than-ideal feel.

Also remember that your logic update rate is **not** mandated by your visual update rate; but if your main loop is driven by the display refresh rate, as in e.g. Android, then best make your logic update evenly divisible into display rate, e.g. for 60Hz display refresh, it's easy enough to do logic 1 in 2 frames (30Hz), or even 1 in 3 frames (20Hz).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont have my update loop tied to display. I didnt know how vsync wast attached to 60Hz. Still, i haven't noticed anything strange playing [this game](http://www.cavestory.org/download/cave-story.php) which is supposed to run at 50. [Here](http://www.destructoid.com/cave-story-creator-talks-inspirations-sequel-and-more-168541.phtml) he explains why he went with 50

Comment: If it's a fullscreen game, the author could be requesting a OpenGL/DirectX context that renders at 50Hz (I'm sorry, I'm not going to download it just to see what the game is.) That is fine - but again vsynced. What I'm saying is - don't let the 50/60Hz issue concern you. Just focus on writing your game *logic*, and if you have speed issues later then run *logic* once for every 2-3 render frames, i.e. at 20 or 30Hz. Then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of using 50 fps is unless you are running on a variable rate display, there will either be tearing or duplicate frames.

Pixel deliberately picked 50 fps, because back when he was writing games, not all computer monitors ran at 60 fps. Sometimes it was 65, or 75, or even 90.

So by selecting 50, he ensured that it would duplicate frames on all computers, and only someone who ran their monitor at 100 fps would get a perfectly stable frame rate, and no one did that at the time. Even really high end was 90. It's also why the game feels floaty and weird.

Nowadays everyone has flatscreens, and pretty much any of them will take 60fps and do the right thing.